# Error when installing RediSearch on centos 7

Tags: python, cmake, redis, redisearch

I am running "make setup" to install RediSearch on linux centos 7. The problem is:

```
make setup

Setting up system...
yum install -q -y ca-certificates
yum install -q -y curl wget
/usr/bin/python2  -m pip install --disable-pip-version-check wheel
/usr/bin/python2  -m pip install --disable-pip-version-check setuptools --upgrade
/home/andrewc/marcus/RediSearch/deps/readies/bin/enable-utf8
 sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command

In /home/bbbb/xxx/RediSearch/deps/readies/bin/enable-utf8:

command failed: { /home/bbbb/xxx/RediSearch/deps/readies/bin/enable-utf8; } >/tmp/tmpoqKXYK 2>&1
make: *** [Makefile:219: setup] Error 1
```

I have tried to reinstall Cmake but still failed to tackle the error

Comment: There is clearly a bug in `/home/andrewc/marcus/RediSearch/deps/readies/bin/enable-utf8` which prevents it from working on your system (probably a Linux `sed` command when you're on a Mac, or vice versa) but if you just want somebody else to solve it for you, Stack Overflow is probably not the correct site for your question.

Comment: https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/readies/blob/e8756faea4ab4a4ee3f3e4c94908465e997bd4e8/bin/enable-utf8#L33 doesn't have any _obvious_ bug but probably experiment with that code in isolation if you want to provide debugging details.

Answer (score 1):

Running on an isolated environment (e.g., Docker container with a volume mount of your repo), you can setup and build RediSearch using:

```
./deps/readies/bin/getpy2
./sbin/system-setup.py
bash -l # enable toolchain
make
```

To diagnose the original issue, the following can be helpful:

```
./deps/readies/bin/getbashdb
bashdb ./deps/readies/bin/enable-utf8
```

Disabling `enable-utf8` altogether in `system-setup.py` can also help, as lack of utf8 support typically causes problems only in CI systems.